# Problemas com git merge

Tags: git

Galera, estou com um problema que nunca tinha pego antes com git..

No nosso flow temos uma branch chamada DEV que é de onde todas as demais saiem. E todas as tarefas após finalizadas passam por um merge da DEV pra branch e depois é criado um pull request pra DEV (afins de evitar conflito, não sei se é o correto, mas o flow é esse) e posteriormente após o code review é feito o merge.

O que aconteceu foi que uma branch saiu do DEV e foi criado alguns comits normais:

```
DEV ------------o---o--o---o---------------
BRANCH    \----o----o----o---
```

Depois de algumas alterações o desenvolvedor fez um merge do DEV pra branch e criou um commit.

```
DEV ------------o---o--o---o---------------
BRANCH    \----o----o----o---\--0 (merge commit)--o-/
```

Fui analisar o commit do merge e não tinha arquivo algum, simplesmente foi um commit de merge sem nenhuma alteração e é ai que o problema começa acontecer.

Entre o período que a  branch ficou ganhando alterações o dev também ganhou e quando foi feito um merge da dev pra branch ela deveria ter ganho todas essas alterações, porém isso não acontece e eu não sei porque.

Se eu fizer o merge usando `git merge dev` dentro da branch ainda sim algumas das alterações não veem, mesmo não tendo mexido nos arquivos especificos que deveriam vir.

Porém se eu criar uma branch do ultimo commit antes do merge e fazer o merge as alterações vem. Só depois do merge que tudo fica bizarro.

Alguem tem alguma dica?

Comment: Paulo, quando situações esquisitas assim ocorre com o Git, é preciso saber quais comandos foram utilizados. Você sabe como o usuário fez o merge? Parece que o merge feito na branch deu conflitos e o usuário simplesmente resolveu tudo aceitando apenas as alterações dele (recusando todas as outras alterações da branch dev). No mais, eu abriria uma nova branch da develop e faria um cherry-pick de cada commit da branch antiga (tirando os merges, claro) para a branch nova.

Comment: Então, eu acredito que foi exatamente isso que aconteceu também. Acabei optando por fazer cherry-pick das diferenças e fazendo um baita trabalho de "de-para" com essas branchs. 

De qualquer modo, obrigado pela resposta, vou continuar fazendo isso mesmo então, estava no caminho certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paulo, quando situações esquisitas assim ocorre com o Git, é preciso saber quais comandos foram utilizados.

Pelo que descreveu, parece que o merge feito na branch deu conflitos e o usuário simplesmente resolveu tudo aceitando apenas as alterações dele (recusando todas as outras alterações da branch `dev`).

No mais, eu abriria uma nova branch da `dev` e faria um `cherry-pick` de cada commit da branch antiga (tirando os merges, claro) para a branch nova.